# Linq Query from Same table with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

My current query which I am trying is

```
 public async Task<ActionStatus<IList<SelectedListViewModel>>> GetProjectMembersByClient(Guid clientId)
    {
var userProjects = _unitofwork.UserProjects;
        var ProjectIds = userProjects.Get(filter: x => x.UserId == clientId).Select(y=> new UserProjects {UserId=y.UserId,ProjectId=y.ProjectId });
}
```

my table format is (Table name:"UserProject")

```
MapId projectId UserID
1      123       89
2      123       69
3      123       36
```

I want to get all userid's who all contains same projectid's when am passing a userid.

Eg : if my parameter is 89(corresponding projectid is 123),i want to get 69 and 36 as my new "UserProjects" model.

NB: userid may have multiple projectid's,in this case also want to get all members from the selected projectid's

Comment: Why are you filtering by UserID rather than ProjectID?

Comment: The userId's are integers, why is the clientId a guid? (`x.UserId == clientId`)

Comment: sorry the User id is a Guid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get such data set with the Linq below.

```
var userIds = userProjects
    .GroupBy(m => m.ProjectId)
    .Where(g => g.Any(m => m.UserId == userId))
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(m => m.UserId))
    .Distinct();
```

This generates the same result as bit's solution + Distinct(). However, I wondered how much they would be different in run time. So, I simply compared process time with both code for data of 10,000 records (randomly generated every time) 100 times. The result was that my solution above was about 1.5 times (or more) faster. This is a result over mono 5.10.1.57 on macOS 10.13.5. If performance matters for you, try it in your environment.

Comment: Thanks in advance,I didn't try but I think it will resolve my issue, Can u please tell me the explanation for using Distinct in this query.

Comment: Distinct remove the duplications in the data set. For example, the user of `userId` (User A) belongs to three projects and there's another user who belongs to two of those (User B). In this case, the result of the Linq above contains three User A and two User B. Distinct removes such duplication and leaves a single User A and a single User B in the result. I guessed that such duplication was not what you wanted so that I used it in this answer.

Comment: Nice Explanation yas Ikeda. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the typos and assuming that `userId` and `clientId` are numeric.
First get the `projectIds` you need,

```
var projectIds = _unitofwork.UserProjects.Where(p=>p.UserId==clientId).Select(p=>p.ProjectId);
```

and then get the user ids associated with those `projectIds`; something like this:

```
var userIds = _unitofwork.UserProjects.Where(p=>projectIds.Contains(p.ProjectId)).Select(p=>p.UserId);
```